# fullCalendar.js dayRender() callback not called in agendaWeek view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Using fullCalendar.js v3, I'm trying to style certain timeslots (not entire days), however the `dayRender()` callback is not called if you're using the `agendaWeek` view.

This appears to be a hole in the plugin (not a bug), so does anyone have a workaround?

```
$('#schedule').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    dayRender: function( date, cell ) {
        // Never logs anything
        console.log('Running dayRender');
    }
});
```

Comment: does the timeslot style vary by day, or only by time? If it only varies by time (e.g. 11.30am would be styled the same way every day) you could just use static CSS.

Comment: It varies by day and time

Comment: one workaround would be to render background events into the relevant timeslots. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/.  N.B. You can't directly use CSS for this task  because the grid that you see on screen is actually made up of two separate tables, both of which have no background, with one layered over the top of the other. So there isn't any specific `<td>` or anything which you can style. I can't say why it's designed like this, but presumably the creator had their reasons. It is a bit awkward though.

Comment: @ADyson - Ah, I was wondering if they had something like that for a workaround. This is perfect, thank you! If you want to submit this as an answer, I'll make it as accepted.

Comment: I've done so, thankyou.

Comment: duplicate of  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593145/fullcalendar-v2-dayrender-for-agenda-view-and-agendaweek/44405508#44405508)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround would be to render background events into the relevant timeslots. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events.

N.B. You can't directly use CSS for this task because the grid that you see on screen is actually made up of two separate tables, both of which have no background, with one layered over the top of the other. So there isn't any specific `<td>` or anything which you can style. I can't say why it's designed like this, but presumably the creator had their reasons. It is a bit awkward though